# Availability of wifi MAC address

Tags: android, wifi, mac-address

I've looked at various answers, but not found the definitive one.

My question is, on an android device with wifi, is the wifi MAC address always available whether wifi is enabled or not? (I know the bluetooth MAC address isn't).

I've found answers which say it definitively is and definitely isn't.

Comment: I thought Android has only one MAC address. Or do you mean MAC of Access Point

Answer (score 0):

I know for shore that your MAC address will never be available an any WAN and LAN connections.
Have grate time of day.